# How to write a Nest query with 2 field which should exists

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elastic-stack

**TL;DR**

Nest is creating an extra inner `Bool.Match` when I try to match more than one thing in a `should` clause (in bool context)

---

### Expected - Query

I am using Nest 5.6.1 and I'm trying to write the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 2,
      "should": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "B"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "A"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "fields.MachineName": "MY_Machine"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "2018-09-03T00:00:00",
              "lt": "2018-09-04T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

### What I  have tried

I tried to achieve it in the following way:

```
var searchResponse = connection.Search<ExcludedCusipsStructLog>(sd => sd
                         .Index(DefaultIndex)
                         .From(0)
                         .Size(1000)
                         .Type(LogType.ProxyLog)
                         .Query(q => q
                             .Bool(b => b
                                .Should(sh => sh
                                        .Exists(e => e
                                        .Field(fi => fi.A)
                                        )
                                      && sh
                                        .Exists(e => e
                                        .Field(fi => fi.B)
                                        )
                                      && sh
                                        .Match(ma => ma
                                        .Field(f => f.MachineName)
                                        .Query("MY_Machine")
                                        )
                                 )
                                .MinimumShouldMatch(2)
                                .Filter(fi => fi
                                        .DateRange(r => r
                                             .Field(f => f.Timestamp)
                                             .GreaterThanOrEquals(dateToSearch)
                                             .LessThan(dateToSearch.AddDays(1))
                                        )
                                 )

                             )
                         )
                    );
```

---

### Actual Result

The problem is that nest generating this request:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "fields.invalidPositionList"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "fields.excludedCusips"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "match": {
                            "fields.MachineName": {
                                "query": "GSMSIMPAPUA01"
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }],
            "filter": [{
                "range": {
                    "@timestamp": {
                        "gte": "2018-09-06T00:00:00",
                        "lt": "2018-09-07T00:00:00"
                    }
                }
            }],
            "minimum_should_match": 2
        }
    }
}
```

---

### More Details

I also figured out that if I look only one field in the Should clause - Nest is creating a good query - what get me to think that I should add the additional fields in a different way (which I didn't found)

Comment: Did you try to provide you matches as separated paramaters like `Should(sh => sh.Exists(), sh => sh.Exists(), sh => sh.Match())` ?

Comment: I just figured it out an hour ago. I was about to upload an answer. THANKS on the tip anyway! It took me an hour to figure it out...

Comment: Good for you! Shoot your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @KozhevnikovDmitry.
I was supposed to use a coma instead of an `&&` i.e. The correct way is:

```
var searchResponse = connection.Search<ExcludedCusipsStructLog>(sd => sd
                         .Index(DefaultIndex)
                         .From(0)
                         .Size(1000)
                         .Type(LogType.ProxyLog)
                         .Query(q => q
                             .Bool(b => b
                                .Should(sh => sh
                                        .Exists(e => e
                                        .Field(fi => fi.A)
                                        )
                                      ,sh => sh
                                        .Exists(e => e
                                        .Field(fi => fi.B)
                                        )
                                      ,sh => sh
                                        .Match(ma => ma
                                        .Field(f => f.MachineName)
                                        .Query("MY_Machine")
                                        )
                                 )
                                .MinimumShouldMatch(2)
                                .Filter(fi => fi
                                        .DateRange(r => r
                                             .Field(f => f.Timestamp)
                                             .GreaterThanOrEquals(dateToSearch)
                                             .LessThan(dateToSearch.AddDays(1))
                                        )
                                 )

                             )
                         )
                    );
```